# AccessibilityService clipboard copy event

Tags: java, android, accessibilityservice

I'm trying to make AccessibilityService get notified about clipboard copy event.

So far I've tried to make work around, so the service would be notified after "copy" button is clicked in popup, but no event is thrown in that situation, I checked all basic events (text selection, type view click etc.)

Is there any possibility to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessibility services don't receive this event. What you could do is check the content of the clipboard after some subset of Accessibility Events.

```
@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent e) {

    switch (e.getEventType()) {
        //This event alone may be enough!
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_SELECTION_CHANGED:

        // If not fall through for these events as well, which would detect things like a "Copy" button activated.
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED:
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CONTEXT_CLICKED:
            checkContentsOfClipboard();

    }
}
```

Comment: Many apps like pdf readers, chrome implement their own text containers, which do not throw selection changed event, the other ones are not thrown too from what I've tested.

Comment: That's why I suggested following other events as well. The fall through will check for selection changed OR view clicked or view context clicked events. This should be the subset of events that could trigger a change. You can always just follow all events, and always check for clipboard changes... if your customers don't care about battery life.

Comment: If you're not catching those events, you have a problem elsewhere. Those events are thrown just fine. Unless someone is using a hardware keyboard to "copy" which is fundamentally different, someone had to interact with the "copy" button in the OS, which will fire a VIEW_CLICKED accessibility event. The trick is listening for it properly.

Comment: Indeed, android studio emulated system did not throw events correctly, after testing it locally on my own phone it turned out that it works, thanks!

Comment: Starting from Android 10, you can't even check the content of the clipboard, no matter how many events you have. Your app has to be focused to reach the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly not possible, as the other answer has written (and from Android 10 you can't even check what's on the clipboard without having an Activity of your own in the foreground), so I've requested to add this API here:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/207842550

Please consider starring.